# AttributeError: type object 'NoDbTestRunner' has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, django, test-runner

I'm trying to create a DiscoverRunner for Django 2.0 and python3 to skip DB creation, but get this error:

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
super().run_from_argv(argv)
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in run_from_argv
parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 254, in create_parser
self.add_arguments(parser)
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 47, in add_arguments
test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)
File "/home/mlmireles/.virtualenvs/risk-analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 306, in get_runner
test_path = test_runner_class.split('.')
AttributeError: type object 'NoDbTestRunner' has no attribute 'split'
```

Here's the code for the runner:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class NoDBTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def teardown_databases(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In the test_class_runner [found here in the Django docs](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/utils.py#L300)  you will notice that the settings.TEST_RUNNER is expecting a string delimited by periods".".  sting.split can be [found here in the python] documentation(https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

So, in your settings file, you should be setting the TEST_RUNNER variable like this:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'yourapp.settings_file.NoDbTestRunner'
```

assuming that your app structure is like the below and your NoDBTestRunner class is also in your settings_file.py file.  If the class is not, you simply change the reference for TEST_RUNNER to point at wherever your NoDbTestRunner is located.

- yourapp folder

  - settings_file.py # this file is where you are setting the variable